# Wrong CRC32 hash in android

Tags: java, android, hash, crc32

I'm calculating CRC32 hash using the below code.

```
CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
crc.update(str.getBytes());
String enc = Long.toHexString(crc.getValue());
```

My problem is that in the output (enc) if the first character is '0' it removes that zero and finally i will get a 7 character long hex string . Can anyone tell me how can i get the full 8 character long hex string if '0' comes as the first character?

Comment: You aren't getting a 'wrong CRC' at all. You're just missing a leading zero. The value is correct. Leading zeros don't alter the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Java Docs for [toHexString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString%28long%29) that is expected behaviour:

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) with no extra leading 0s.

There are a number of ways you could go about it such as adding a leading zero character at the start of the string until the desired length is achieved, although another way would be to use the `String.format` method that allows the use of a C-style format specification:

```
String enc = String.format("%08X", crc.getValue());
```

Here's a complete working example for regular Java that includes computation with a leading zero:

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "c";
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        crc.update(str.getBytes());
        String enc = String.format("%08X", crc.getValue());
        System.out.println(enc);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I'm also using this same concept of checking the string length and adding '0' until desired length is achieved...

Answer (score 1):

Hi please have a look here
it was working for me, please try.

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class CalculateCRC32ChecksumForByteArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Java Code Geeks - Java Examples";

        // get bytes from string
        byte bytes[] = input.getBytes();

        Checksum checksum = new CRC32();

        // update the current checksum with the specified array of bytes
        checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        // get the current checksum value
        long checksumValue = checksum.getValue();

        System.out.println("CRC32 checksum for input string is: " + checksumValue);

    }

}
```

Comment: my problem is when that checkSumValue is converted to hex string using the method toHexString()... it is giving me 7 character long hex string..when i check it on the online crc32 generator it is giving me a 8 char long hex string starting with '0(zero)' and the rest 7 characters are the same...so while converting the checkSumValue the '0' is truncated which results in a 7 character hex string...how do i solve this?

Comment: hi i am bit confused but please have a look at http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/security/calculate-the-crc-sum-of-a-file/ hope it can help you